# Azure custom script stuck in Transitioning state

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a virtual machine on my azure account, and I want to pass a simple powershell script that should just open up the Microsoft Paint program.

The powershell script is:

```
& "C:\Windows\system32\mspaint.exe"
```

This is the code that fetches the vm, and tries to apply this script on the remote vm.

```
var testingVm = _azure.VirtualMachines.GetById(
            "...");
        testingVm.Update()
            .DefineNewExtension("InstallSoftware")
            .WithPublisher("Microsoft.Compute")
            .WithType("CustomScriptExtension")
            .WithVersion("1.9")
            .WithPublicSetting("fileUris", new string[]
            {
                "https://.../powershellscripts/OpenPaint.ps1"
            })
            .WithProtectedSetting("Url", "https://.../powershellscripts/gource-0.42-setup.exe")
            .WithProtectedSetting("commandToExecute", "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File OpenPaint.ps1")
            .Attach()
            .Apply();
```

The files get downloaded and the script is correctly place in the C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.9\Downloads\0 folder, bu Paint isn't open, and on the Azure Portal the state of the extnesion is forever set to "Transitioning". (I have also made sure that the vm has paint in that directory, and that the execution policy is set to Bypass).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure nothing is wrong. It launches paint under system context (hence you cant see it on the screen) and its stuck there forever. So i guess it works exactly as you designed it (but the design is flawed).

Just try doing something meaningful in the script (instead of what you are doing):

```
get-process > c:\1.txt
```

Comment: Just as something extra, how would I be able to pass arguments to that powershell script from this C# code?

Comment: cannot help you with that sadly. never worked with c# sdk